# Visual Studio: "Current Document" option missing from Quick Replace dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2010, find, replace

This picture says it all.  Anyone know what's wrong? Haven't done anything other than restart VS at this point.

[image: Picture says it all]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is actually running and the current document is part of the running code, you cannot modify it : the search and replace won't allow a replace on the current document.

Comment: Steve, good point.  This happens when Visual Studio is not running, though maybe Visual Studio thinks it's in some sort of a running state even though it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that this is to do with whether Visual Studio running or not... it 'may' also happen when it is running, but VS2010 regularly loses the `Current Document` option.

I usually bring it back by following the process below:

1. First search for a word using another option, eg. `Current Project`, or `Entire Solution`.
2. After VS2010 finds a match (usually in another file), I then return to the original file in the designer and the `Current Document` option has 'usually' returned.

In step 2, it appears to be important that VS2010 finds a match before the `Current Document` option returns. Usually, the option will re-appear in the other file (where it found a match) and you can set it there or when you return back to your original file.

I hope that helps.